# View only ERROR column in the result of `docker service ps xxx`?

Tags: docker, command-line-interface

I know about the use of `--format` option, but somehow it does not work for some fields (works for `ID` field), maybe the object graph is something hidden here.

Here are all columns shown when running just `docker service ps my_service_id`:

> ID - NAME - IMAGE - NODE - DESIRED STATE - CURRENT STATE - ERROR - PORTS

Now I just want to show the ERROR column for easier reading by using the following command instead:

```
docker service ps --format '{{.ERROR}}' my_service_id
```

However it does not work and prints the following error:

> Template parsing error: template: :1:3: executing "" at <.ERROR>: can't evaluate field ERROR in type *task.taskContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to use capital letters in combination with the `--format` flag, but what does works is using e.g. `'{{ .Status }}'`. It is case sensitive it seems and the rendered table will always have capital letters on each column, probably done on the client side (Docker CLI).

The returned (and rendered) data type when issuing different sub commands will have exported fields in them, in Golang that means that the field name starts with a capital letter. This is not always the case though, e.g. when using [acronyms](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms). I might be wrong about this given that we're using [Golang templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) under the hood here.

Does the following command output what you wanted?

```
docker service ps --format '{{ .Error }}' my_service_id
```

Comment: sorry that I don't have access to my working laptop now to check this out. I'll get back to you soon. Looks like this is very promising and may work. I've just tried with `.ID` and it worked so I did not think of the issue of case-sensitivity here.

Comment: Actually, field names such as ID is special atleast in the context of naming conventions in Golang: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms. I can totally understand why you tried capital case on the rest of the columns!

Comment: It is case sensitive, so this is the correct answer. I've posted a separate answer for how you can determine the field names.

Answer (score 2):

Fields are case sensitive in the format output. To determine the correct name, I typically format the output as json and make it pretty with `jq`:

```
$ docker service ps --format '{{ json . }}' traefik_traefik | jq .
{
  "CurrentState": "Running 15 hours ago",
  "DesiredState": "Running",
  "Error": "",
  "ID": "lrmsc96zdfei",
  "Image": "localhost:5000/bmitch/traefik:1.7",
  "Name": "traefik_traefik.1",
  "Node": "bmitch",
  "Ports": ""
}
{
  "CurrentState": "Failed 15 hours ago",
  "DesiredState": "Shutdown",
  "Error": "\"task: non-zero exit (255)\"",
  "ID": "y6ocu5s2k7l2",
  "Image": "localhost:5000/bmitch/traefik:1.7",
  "Name": "traefik_traefik.1",
  "Node": "bmitch",
  "Ports": ""
}
{
  "CurrentState": "Complete 2 weeks ago",
  "DesiredState": "Shutdown",
  "Error": "",
  "ID": "nt8tsd7jfsgl",
  "Image": "localhost:5000/bmitch/traefik:1.7",
  "Name": "traefik_traefik.1",
  "Node": "bmitch",
  "Ports": ""
}
```

From there you can pick your desired fields:

```
$ docker service ps --format '{{ .ID }}: {{ .Error }}' traefik_traefik
lrmsc96zdfei:
y6ocu5s2k7l2: "task: non-zero exit (255)"
nt8tsd7jfsgl:
```